# What's the point of os.error?

Tags: python

Why does Python's `os` module contain [`error`, an alias for `OSError`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.error)?

Is there a reason to ever spell it `os.error`? `OSError` certainly seems more consistent with all the other built-in exceptions.

I hoped `os.py` would shed some light, but it uses `error` sometimes and `OSError` others.

It seems goofy to have an extra name for one of the exceptions, yet it survives into Python 3.0. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [`OSError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) says that it was added in version 1.5.2. My guess is that `error` predates this a little and in an effort to remain backwards-compatible to code written for Python before 1.5.2 `error` was made an alias for `OSError`.

Comment: Yep. And -- we overlooked this detail in the move to Python 3, so os.error is _still_ there even in 3.1 (oops -- probably too late to fix now... sorry!).